# Unable to access my page or WP Admin

Tags: wp-admin, errors, 500-internal-error

I've been trying to get into my page for 3 days. I keep getting this message...

This page isn’t workingstaunchtopteam.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Can anyone please help?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 1):

there might be these possibilities please check both the cases

- Please allow the debugging mode in your wp-config file
  `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` make it true.
- If after enabling the debug you didn't get any fatal error, then this
  problem is related to your hosting server, do check with their
  support.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly check the Error Log file to know the exact error. HTTP 500 error can be due to a lot of things.

Hope you tried with the basic things first -

1. Disable all the plugins and check.
2. Try to switch the theme to the default Twenty20.

Comment: Can you kindly add a few more details to your answer? Thanks!